# ASP NET read session from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a WebForms application in wich I store array of strings in Session object and I need
to get this array in javascript code. Maybe someone can provide any solution, how should i do this?

Here is my code:

```
    function loadAnswers() {
        var answers = '<%=Session("answers")%>';
    }
```

but is doesn't work and answerss variable contain simple string after assignment. ('System.String[]')

Comment: You are initializing answers as a string. Sort of like doing "var answers = 'some value';" you have to initialize and populate answers like any other array in javascript. "var answers = ['a1', 'a2', ...];"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(I assume u use VB) You can use a code like this:

```
function loadAnswers() {
   var answers = ['<%= String.Join("','", CType(Session("answers"), String()))%>'];
}
```

It actually joins your array into a string, that is formatted into JS array representation.

So for example if you have an array like this

```
Session("answers") = New String() {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}
```

It will prodice a line like this

```
var answers = ['aaa','bbb','ccc'];
```

Which will be a real JS array. If you need a simple string instead, you can use

```
var answers = '<%= String.Join(",", CType(Session("answers"), String()))%>';
```

which will produce

```
 var answers = 'aaa,bbb,ccc';
```

Comment: Have to make sure that the answers don't contain any '

Comment: @the_lotus yup, additional checks/conversions might be in order, at the very least escape the apostrophe \' in the resulting string

Comment: -1: `New String() {"Mixed O'quotes ""succeeded"""}`. Generating correct JS/HTML/XML with string concatenation is major pain - try not to do so.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Um.. see my comment above?

Comment: I don't think comment which essentially says that code does not really work for arbitrary strings makes it good suggestion. If you'd put comment inline it may be ok (also it still would look wired - but may be ok for OP).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov SO is not supposed to provide a full-blown code for the solution. And any code can encounter unanticipated scenario, it's up to OP to augment and build upon it. But I do thank you for downvote, it made my rep a cool looking number.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter :) you expect way too much of visitors of SO...

Answer (score 1):

If you serialize the `answers` object to JSON, then you should be able to access it programatically from JavaScript.

```
var answers = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Session("answers")) %>;
```

---

**UPDATE:** Below is a working example using four different types of data (string, number, collection, object). This illustrates how JSON serialized from the server can be used as a JavaScript object literal client-side.

**Code-behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebFormsTestApp
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected string Name = "Alice Student";
        protected decimal GPA = 3.84M;
        protected List<string> Classes = new List<string>() { "World History", "Algebra II", "English", "Phys Ed", "Latin I", "Home Economics" };
        protected School School = new School() { Name = "Jefferson High School", County = "Hamilton County", Ranking = 5 };
    }

    public class School
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public int Ranking { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ASPX:**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormsTestApp._Default" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Name) %>;
    var gpa = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(GPA) %>;
    var classes = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Classes) %>;
    var school = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(School) %>;
    alert(name + ' goes to ' + school.Name + ', has a ' + gpa + ' GPA, and takes ' + classes.length + ' classes.');
</script>
```

Comment: thanks! was helpful!